# Cannot access value of elements in XML through XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I have an XML file which I need to transform to some other XML.

The XML file makes use of namespaces, so I included the definition of those in my XSL file to.

For some reason I cannot explain, the value-of selects give no value back.

Just to make sure it has nothing to do with the names of elements with namespaces I also included en element "id" between the elements with dcterms: in the name.

To make it easy I provide the link to the XML file which has an inline reference to the XSL file used:
http://inception.kbenp.net:7080/dev/72174_1.xml

UPDATE:
To solve the issues with namespaces all together I will parse the XML files before saving them with a stylesheet that removes the namespaces:
http://inception.kbenp.net:7080/dev/removenamespaces.xsl

That way my other stylesheet can be much more simple.

Comment: In FireFox with Firebug you can see that the XML structure I defined in my XSL is there, but the values are missing.

Comment: Please post your XML here - along with your XSLT and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the namespace with a prefix like this:

```
xmlns:c="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/cvdr/terms/"
```

and use the prefix "c" in the xpaths as the default namespace in your XML is the namespace above and all the elements fall under it.

e.g.,

```
<xsl:value-of select="c:cvdr/c:meta/c:owmskern/c:id"/>
```

I see that you are missing the prefixes in the XPaths in your XSLT.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the possible answer. The thing is that we get the XML as files as is, so with the declaration of namespaces like you can see in the XML document (so without the xmlns:c= and with the xmlns=). So How should my XSL be made so that I can retrieve the values of the elements that you can find in my current XSL?

Comment: To solve the issues with namespaces all together I will parse the XML files before saving them with a stylesheet that removes the namespaces:
http://inception.kbenp.net:7080/dev/removenamespaces.xsl 

That way my other stylesheet can be much more simple. But thanks for the answer. It set me on the right path.

Comment: Yes, you can remove the namespaces from your XML but, you are doing over work by doing that. Usually, we change the XSL to get the expected output and not change the input XML so that it works with the existing XSL.